# UIDatepicker toolbar not working in landscape mode in ios swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, toolbar, uidatepicker

Application working on both landscape and portrait. Using UIDatepicker to pick the date. Here UIDatepicker code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //Text Field Connection
    @IBOutlet weak var txtDatePicker: UITextField!
    //Uidate picker
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //show date picker
        showDatePicker()
    }
    func showDatePicker(){
        //Formate Date
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        //ToolBar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        //done button & cancel button
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "donedatePicker")
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "cancelDatePicker")
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)

        // add toolbar to textField
        txtDatePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        // add datepicker to textField
        txtDatePicker.inputView = datePicker

    }
    func donedatePicker(){
        //For date formate
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        txtDatePicker.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        //dismiss date picker dialog
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    func cancelDatePicker(){
        //cancel button dismiss datepicker dialog
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

UIDatePicker toolbar working fine in portrait mode. 
[image]

change the app in landscape mode the toolbar get hide.

[image]

How to fix this issue help.

Google it and refer some link:

> [Add a Done button within a pop-up datePickerView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048469/add-a-done-button-within-a-pop-up-datepickerview-in-swift)

It will not workout to me. Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I think you need to set the frame size of date picker i.e self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))

Comment: update the answer in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the frame for datepicker.

```
self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a bug in `iOS 11` and which is not appearing in `iOS 12`. Please refer this in apple developer forums.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81650

Fix:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let item = textField.inputAssistantItem
    item.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
    item.trailingBarButtonGroups = []

    //Your code here....
}
```

Also please have a look at this link once

[Custom Keyboard InputAccessoryView not visible in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560734/custom-keyboard-inputaccessoryview-not-visible-in-ios-11/44900186#44900186)

Comment: How to implement this code to fix my issue.. help me struggling here,,

Comment: Add the above code inside your UITextFieldDelegate method

Comment: Try make a toolbar as global and set toolbar.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight

Comment: @saravanar Add date picker in story board, and set the reference.. I tried with your above code in my project and its working perfectly. The only difference is I added date picker in storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the info @kalpa. Please try to add datePicker in the storyboard and try once, saravanar.